# directive hoslistener to image tag with load event - angular4

Tags: angular

I'm trying to get a directive using hostlistener to detect when images are completed loaded with angular4

```ts
    <img imgDirective src="124.jpg">

    @HostListener('load', ['$event.target']) 
    public onLoad(event) {
        this.img = false;
    }
```

Then if the load is complete I output the value using an EventEmitter, however, the hostlistener event seems not working at all. Does any one knows why?if I a change the event on the hostlistener as below? the event works, but not for image tag. Do you know if this is possible?

```ts
    @HostListener('window:load', ['$event.target']) 
    public onLoad(event) {
        this.img = false;
    }
```

I got the event form https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

What events can we use in angular4? is a limited list?

Comment: Use @Inputs() and @Outputs. new image is inserted emit loading = true image is done loading emit loading false. and you also  use HostBinding to chnage the src when image is done loading.

Comment: I try this method and only works for the first time and not for dynamic images, seems that the directive is not updating the values

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[imgDirective]',
})
class ImgDirective {
  @Input() imgDirective:string;

  constructor(private element:ElementRef){
    element.nativeElement.src = 'resources/spinner.png';
  } 

  @HostListener('load', ['$event'])
  onLoad() {
    this.element.nativeElement.src = this.imgDirective;
  }
}
```

and use it like

```ts
<img [imgDirective]="124.jpg">
```

Comment: Not helping on the issue at all, but I'm interested in your approach. I have a question about that : would it be possible to set the width & height of the picture while it's loading, and cente the spinner in this container ?

Comment: Please provide more information what problem you're actually trying to solve. Sure you can set any property of the image element.

Comment: I'm not trying to solve any problem (and I'm not the OP), but your answer interested me, this is a really good approach, similar to what imagesLoaded do, and I would've liked to know how you could make a container the size of the image, and center the spinner in it, while the image loads. That's all !

Comment: The only issue I see is how you get the size, and on what event, because onload is called once the picture is loaded ! That's actually my initial question to you, not the one I asked, sorry

Comment: That question reveals a flaw in my design :-/
Actually I'd use two image tags, wrap it in a custom image component and use `*ngIf` to either show either the spinner or the actual image.
There is no way to wait for the load event of the actual image, when the spinner is shown, because then the browser wouldn't bother loading the actual image.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer your solution is good, but only works on the first load, the thing I've dynamic images, by changing the src url, and when I click on each thumbnail the spinner doesn't load or the directive doesn't update

Comment: @carlosdv4 as mentioned in my last comment. I'd create a custom component with 2 img tags and an *ngIf to show one or the other and do the rest in the component. Your information about your actual use case wasn't enough to think about a concrete solution. So if you could elaborate, I could outline the approach in more detail.

Comment: Actually it should be `[hidden]="isLoaded"` on the `<img>` tag instead of `*ngIf` that shows the actual image, otherwise there also won't be a `load` event.

Comment: I don't use *ngIf

Comment: Was just an additional hint to my suggested approach.

Comment: No pb GZ, the load event on @hostlistener only works for the first time, I manage to detect the changes of the src URL with ngOnchanges, but I can't find a way to reload the load event again

Comment: You can use `*ngIf` in addition to `[hidde]="..."` if you want. If you have `<img *ngIf="condition">` and inject `private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef`, you can use `this.condition = false; this.cdRef.detectChanges(); this.condition = true;` to get the img element removed and readded. I'm sure the `load` event will fire again. If you need more support, please add your current code to the question and I'll have another look.